# Mysql order by if condition - wrong order

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I got a simple table:

```
CREATE  TABLE `dev_a4a`.`test` (   `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT ,   `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,   `priority` INT NOT
NULL ,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

with following rows:

```
id|type |priority
1 |long |8
2 |long |3
3 |short|9
4 |short|1
```

I want to get rows ordered by condition:

```
SELECT (RAND() * priority) as prio, type, priority FROM test
ORDER BY (IF(type = 'short', '2', prio)) DESC, id DESC
```

As a result I got rows not ordered by if condition. Every time it looks like it's random. Here's one of possible results:

```
prio                 | type  | priority
'0.05013570194145264', 'long', '8'
'2.9015473750434326', 'long', '3'
'0.320064320527077', 'short', '1'
'7.598900996706356', 'short', '9'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Expected result:

```
prio                 | type  | priority
'2.9015473750434326', 'long', '3'  <- order by prio
'7.598900996706356', 'short', '9'  <- order by common value 2  
'0.320064320527077', 'short', '1'  <- order by common value 2
'0.05013570194145264', 'long', '8' <- order by prio
```

Comment: Provide result set that should be in your sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I resolved that issue:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN type = 'short' THEN 2 ELSE RAND() * priority END AS prio, type, priority FROM test ORDER BY prio DESC, id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
SELECT (RAND() * priority) as prio, type, priority ,CASE `type`
       WHEN 'short' THEN 2
       WHEN 'long' THEN 1

    END AS  t
FROM test
ORDER BY 3 DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: dont use ORDER BY 3 is error prone when you alter column positions... just use ORDER BY priority

Comment: In your example rows are always ordered by column 'priority'. I want to give 'short' types common random value, and calculate random value for every 'long' type based on its priority, then order by this values.